# iPhone EXC_BAD_ACCESS with NSMutableArray of strings

Tags: objective-c, ios, nsmutablearray, exc-bad-access

Problem context is a ViewController with several button handlers and a scores.list data file of 1000 NSString objects. If I click on buttonOne, the handler code checks if the file scores.list exists in the User Documents directory. If yes, it loads the data in an NSMutableArray called score, if not it creates the NSMutableArray in memory (to be stored on disk later) like this:

```
- (void)readScores
{
    // Setup path + filename pathUserDocDirScorelist);
    ...
    // test for presence scores.list in documents dir
    if ([fileManager fileExistsAtPath: pathUserDocDirScorelist])
    {   // Read scores.plist into NSMutableArray
        score = [NSMutableArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:pathUserDocDirScorelist];
    } else { // Initialize empty scores array with 1000 empty NSString entries
        score = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        int i;
        for(i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
            [score addObject:@""];
        }
    }
    // at this point there is always a valid array score with 1000 entries
}
```

Basically this code works; in both cases (reading data from scores.list or in-mem build-up) I can verify in the debugger (with 'po score') that an array with 1000 entries is present afterwards.

Now comes the problem that is blocking me for 2 days now:

**In the handler of buttonTwo, statements like [score count] crash, but only in case the array score gets its data from disk, not if build-up in memory.** In the first case is the array still valid though until the last line of handler code of buttonOne, but then 'evaporates' as soon as the array is addressed in a next handler (EXC_BAD_ACCESS).

No, it is not caused by a premature release statement, since there are none (yet) in my entire app. :)
(not concerned with memory leaks yet).

**How is this possible that within one view a NSMutableArray is valid at the end of button handler 1, but invalid at the beginning of the next button handler 2 if no explicit release statement is executed in between?**

Extra info:
**ViewController.h**:

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController {
    NSMutableArray *score;
    ...
}
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *score;
...
- (IBAction) buttonOne: (id) sender;
- (IBAction) buttonTwo: (id) sender;
@end
```

And in **ViewController.m** I have:

```
@synthesize score;
...

- (IBAction) buttonOne: (id) sender {
    if (score == nil) {
        [self readScores];
    }
    ...
    NSLog(@"Number of entries in score = %i", [score count]); // never crashes
}


- (IBAction) buttonTwo: (id) sender {
    NSLog(@"Number of entries in score = %i", [score count]); // **crash point**
}
```

P.S. I tried NSZombieEnabled by starting the app with alt/cmd/R and adding 'NSZombieEnabled=YES', but that does not result in extra information in the debug console.

Comment: Have you tried it with using self.score instead of score only? Change all occurences to self.score.

Comment: Yes!!!! That seems to do the trick! Does that mean that there is a mysterious second score variable around?

Comment: When you assign the array to score without the self, it is not retained. I think it disappears sometime after readScores() has finished.

Comment: yes there is a mysterious second variable around. `self->score` is created by the `@synthesize` directive. You can use `@synthesize score = _score` to change this.

Comment: also the reason your array isn't retained (as ott said) is because assigning array to `this->score` is just assigning a pointer to your array. Using `self.score = array` is equivalent to `[ self setScore:array]`

Answer (score 2):

It's always a little dangerous to do this:

```
score = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
```

outside of an `init` method. Because, the problem is that perhaps your method `readScores` is executed twice. I'd guess it almost certainly is.

What happens then is the the first `scores` object is never released. That causes a memory leak and sooner or later you get the dreaded `EXC_BAD_ACCESS`.

So, the best thing is either to first check:

```
if (score)
{
    [score release];
}
```

Or, alternatively, set up `scores` as a synthesized retained object in your `.h` file. Then you can replace your code as follows and let everything happen automatically:

```
self.scores = [NSMutableArray array];
```

Note that here, I didn't use:

```
self.scores = [NSMutableArray alloc] init];
```

because that would cause two retains to happen, and of then EXC_BAD_ACCESS due to over-retention.

Comment: I agree he should use `self.scores` and `[NSMutableArray array];` both for consistency with the `arrayWithContentsOfFile` on the other side of the if/else and the auto-retain. However a `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` is caused by accessing a pointer which had it's contents released. This is often caused by accidentally over-releasing an object or failure to  assign nil to variable after releasing the object. Over retaining like you mentioned with `self.scores = [NSMutableArray alloc] init];` would cause a memory leak, but not result in a `EXC_BAD_ACCESS`.